# Cannot resolve 'react-native'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I am trying to import react-native module into my react app. When I start my app server using 'npm start', I get the following error :

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'

I have done following steps:

- cleaned npm cache using 'npm cache verify'
- deleted node_modules
- rerun the command 'npm install'
- checked package.json file if it has react-native dependency listed

Nothing worked for me. Please help!!

Comment: @Think-Twice but I am already using npm. Wouldn't mixing package managers mess up everything? Please advise.

Comment: npm works fine, you don't need Yarn. After you `npm install`, can you verify if `./node_modules/react-native` exists?

Comment: Sorry are you using Atom?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yes it does.

Comment: @Think-Twice I am doing this on windows, considering you are referring to os

Comment: I mean Atom Editor not OS

Comment: I am using sublime. Is there anything to do with editors and react?

Comment: Can you try with npm start --reset-cache

Comment: doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate your app using the react native CLI.  Use the command npm install -g react-native-cli, then use react-native init *ProjectName* and after that try to run the project.

If you cannot create a new app for any reason, try to install the react-native-cli anyway and try to run *react-native run-android* or *react-native run-ios* (depending on the plataform you want to use as a tester_ instead of npm start.